# Crystal REport throws error on formula field while exporting to pdf using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, dataset

I have crystal report that is build on a view that uses 2 tables and around 47 columns.  this was created in cr 2008. now I have to import this report into c# asp.net  project and use dataset I have created to work as a data source for this same report.  it giving error stating that a formula fields that are created using a view are throwing an error  which is something like this

```
This field name is not known.
    Details: errorKindError in File statement {C4B51C11-81BC-4D27-9886-23BE50D5A9D0}.rpt:
    Error in formula  Location: 
    'if {statements_view.DOC_TYPE} = 'RU' then
    {statements_view.BUNUMBER_RU}
    else {statements_view.BUNUMBER}
```

am I missing something here ?

here is my code so far

```
string connetionString = null;
OracleConnection connection;
OracleDataAdapter OracleAdapter;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string firstSql = null;
string secondSql = null;

connetionString = "DATA SOURCE= blah blah ";
firstSql = "select * from STATEMENT_DOMESTIC";
secondSql = "Select * from STATEMENT_DOM_DETAILS";
connection = new OracleConnection(connetionString);

connection.Open();
OracleAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(firstSql, connection);
OracleAdapter.Fill(ds, "Tables[0]");
OracleAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = secondSql;
OracleAdapter.Fill(ds, "tables[1]");

OracleAdapter.Dispose();
connection.Close();
// GridView1.DataSource = ds;
//  GridView1.DataBind();

ReportDocument reportDoc = new ReportDocument();
reportDoc.Load(@"c:\statement.rpt");
reportDoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables);

 ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions =new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = @"d:\Converte5_1_13.pdf";
CrExportOptions = reportDoc.ExportOptions;
{
CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;

}
reportDoc.Export();
}
```

is there a problem with my dataset or am I missing something here..
any guidance on this issue is

Comment: Its probably of the formula that you have implemented in report, try checking syntax

Comment: the formula works  it is a copy from production.   I think I am missing something  either in dataset or  export option  or load function